# How to connect the Blackberry simulator with BES and configure the Gmail?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I want to configure the GMail id in the Blackberry simulator. For that, first i have to connect with the BES. To do this, i tried with BlackBerry MDS Simulator and Blackberry BBM simulator. But everytime it is saying : " **activation request failed. a service connection is unavailable** "

Can anyone configure the mail account in Blackberry simulator?? Please help..

Comment: Could you give a sign why do you need this?

Comment: Basically i have to configure my mail account in the simulator..In my current app, i have to open the attached file of the mails using my app..So for that, i want to configure my email id

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you able to connect live account (never tried), but read this:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Configure-email-simulation-support-in-the-BlackBerry-MDS/ta-p/446113

But you could use ESS for email receiving sending test:
http://www.blackberryforums.com/general-blackberry-discussion/62205-please-help-ess-email-server-simulator.html or 
http://code-dojo.blogspot.nl/2010/04/how-to-send-email-in-blackberry.html

Comment: I tried the first link..but no luck. Using the second link also i have tried. But how can i add the Email account in the simulator, that is not pretty clear..

Comment: Run MDS first. No needs to create it. Just start sending email from sim

Comment: No, i need to create my Gmail Account in the SIMULATOR. SO that i can see the mails from my Gmail Inbox. I want to configure it in my local system.

Comment: Why just do that way I suggested and forward the mails that you want to test or create mails with attachments and send them to simulator?

Comment: No. Actually if i have to develop one application using that i can open my EMail attachment. So to run the application in the simulator and check whether i can open the attachement using my app, i need this ESS things..

Comment: And in the link, it is telling, First i have to run the ESS which will open a window. In the window, i have to give the details of POP and SMTP ports and run in to Stand Alone mode. I gave the GMAIL POP and SMTP port numbers and my gmail name and Email ID. After that, i pressed the Launch button. Then i ran MDS(Which is opening a black command prompt and executing the commands). Then i ran the JDE simulator. But after that i am not getting how i will check the mails..

Comment: Just send email to the account

Comment: But in the simulator, where i will be able to see the mails??

Comment: In the device inbox I guess. You should also see notification indicator and blinking lights about new email

Comment: Ok. I didn't try use Gmail. I used everything as described in article/post with localhost. I was able to send email from outlook and receive it on the sim and vise verse

Comment: Ok. Suppose i have Mozila Thunderbird installed in my system. The POP and SMTP port number is 110 and 25. Now if i give the same port number for ESS, will it work?? Here i will not configure gmail. i want to configure my office mails..